# Make the width of the dropdown list different from the width of the dropdown button

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, dropdown, fluent-ui

I would like to realize a [dropdown](https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/preview-components-dropdown--default), where the width of the dropdown button is not necessarily equal to the width of the dropdown list.

I know that we can use `style={{ minWidth: '200px' }}` to control the width of the dropdown button and dropdown list. Now, I would like to make the width of the dropdown list `500px`.

I tried to set `.fui-Listbox { width: 500px }` in the stylesheet, but it did not work.

Does anyone know how to do that?

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cejuzs?file=App.tsx,style.css,index.html

```
import {
  FluentProvider,
  webLightTheme,
  makeStyles,
  shorthands,
} from '@fluentui/react-components';
import {
  Dropdown,
  Option,
  DropdownProps,
} from '@fluentui/react-components/unstable';
import { TextField } from '@fluentui/react';
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default class Grouped extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  land = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Ferret', 'Hamster'];

  render() {
    return (
      <FluentProvider
        className="fluent-provider"
        style={{ display: 'flex' }}
        theme={webLightTheme}
      >
        <Dropdown
          className="drop-down"
          style={{ minWidth: '200px' }}
          placeholder="Select an animal"
        >
          {this.land.map((option) => (
            <Option key={option}>{option}</Option>
          ))}
        </Dropdown>
      </FluentProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:** Following pier farrugia's answer, I tried to use `.fui-Listbox { width: 500px !important; }`. It did make the width of the dropdown list `500px`, however it impacted all the dropdowns in the project, which is not what I want. I tried to add classes and wrote selectors such as `.drop-down .fui-Listbox { width: '500px' !important; }` and `.drop-down-2 .fui-Listbox { width: '100%' !important; }`, but it did not work. I guess it's because under the mode of dropdown, `.fui-Listbox` is not a child class of `drop-down-2` or `.fluent-provider-2`. Does anyone know how to properly write the selectors to limit the impact only to the dropdown I target?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-51hiro?file=App.tsx,style.css,index.html

Answer (score 0):

in the code you have :

```js
<Dropdown
          className="drop-down"
          style={{ width: '100px' }}
          placeholder="Select an animal"
        >
```

Your style 100px is generated dynamically.

Change in style even with !important is not working.

Modify the the line

style={{ width: '100px' }}

to

style={{ width: '500px' }}

Comment: Are you sure this is what I'm after?

Comment: you asked list 500px, I tried in your stackblitz, that works there. Try in your stackblitz, you'll see

Answer (score 0):

To change only the width of the dropdown list, you have to use the `style` or the `className` tag for that specific dropdown slot (`listbox`):

```
    <Dropdown
      className="drop-down"
      style={{ minWidth: '200px' }}
      placeholder="Select an animal"
      listbox={{style: {width: "500px"}}}
    >
      {this.land.map((option) => (
        <Option key={option}>{option}</Option>
      ))}
    </Dropdown>
```

or if you want to keep using your stylesheet

```
    <Dropdown
      className="drop-down"
      style={{ minWidth: '200px' }}
      placeholder="Select an animal"
      listbox={{className: "custom-dropdown-width"}}
    >
      {this.land.map((option) => (
        <Option key={option}>{option}</Option>
      ))}
    </Dropdown>
```

and in your stylesheet

```
.custom-dropdown-width {
  width: '500px' !important;
}
```